# Getting input value and save it to array

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate through the table and save input values to the array, but I get js error:

```
Object doesn't support property of method 'find'
```

Here is my code:

```
function Elem(tex, check, r, c)
{
    this.text = tex;
    this.checkbox = check;
    this.row = r;
    this.column = c;
}

var Elems = [];

function fill()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("tab");
    for(var i=table.rows.length-1;  i>=2; --i)
    {
        for(var j=table.rows[i].cells.length-1; j>=1 ; j=j-2)
        {
            var check = $(table.rows[i].cells[j-1]).find('input'); 
            check = check.is(":checked");
            var ans = $(table.rows[i].cells[j]).find('input'); 
            ans = ans.val();
            var ans = new Elem(ans, check, i, j/2);
            Elems.push(ans);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how my table looks:

```
...
<table id="tab">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <strong>delete row</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong>checkbox info</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong>description</strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>delete column</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type='checkbox' name='delColumn_1'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name="delRow_1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='check' name="ele.check"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' name="ele.text" required="required"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
...
```

And I want to get text value from ele.text and checkbox value from ele.check. I will be very grateful for help.

Comment: `.find()` is a jQuery method, meaning that you cannot use it without including the jQuery library. It's not a native DOM method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At best guess, it appears you are mixing traditional JavaScript and jQuery without understanding the connection.

Take the line:

```
var check = table.rows[i].cells[j-1].find('input'); //err
```

If you simply break this apart, piece by piece, you will eventually find the problem.

```
var check = table.rows[i]
```

Then, if returns a non-null value, add to it:

```
var check = table.rows[i].cells[j-1]
```

Than should also be non-null, so add the last bit to it.

```
var check = table.rows[i].cells[j-1].find('input'); //err
```

And that should error out, as there is no `find` method on a `td` element.

However, `find` *is* a well-known jQuery method so it is likely that you meant to

- Include a reference to jQuery in your code
- Change it to jQuery syntax
- `var check = $(table.rows[i].cells[j-1]).find('input');`

Or, you could also look at using

```
table.rows[i].cells[j-1].querySelector("input");
```

Which I haven't tested, but should do what you want.

Comment: Yes I mess a little bit, I use in other function jquery because I don't need to have index, and forget that find is a jQuery method. Thanks for detailed explanation! Also querySelector of course works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Find() is a method that is provided on elements by jQuery. If you want to use it, you have to first access the jQuery object.

```
$("#tab tr td").each(function() {
     var ans= $(this).find("input").val();
     // do stuff here
});
```

Small [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/862evoc4/). You can find more details about the find method [in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/).